# AspNet Core Integration Test For SignalR

Tags: asp.net-core, signalr, integration-testing

Is there a way to test `SignalR` using `TestServer` generated as part of [integration tests](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/test/integration-tests)?

All my retries to perform a handshake to the `TestServer` instance failed with Exception

> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException : No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it

Running in `Debug`/`Console`/`IIS` works perfectly

**Server Code**

```cs
public void Configure(...)
{
    ...
    app.UseSignalR(router => router.MapHub<MockHub>("/ws"));
    ...
}
```

**TestCode**

```cs
var server = factory.Server;
var connection = new HubConnectionBuilder()
    .WithUrl(server.BaseAddress)
    .Build();
await connection.StartAsync();
```

Answer (score 6):

Looks like `TestServer` requires you to use the `HttpMessageHandler` created by it, so change your code to

```cs
builder.WithUrl(new Uri(server.BaseAddress, "ws"), o =>
{
    o.HttpMessageHandlerFactory = _ => server.CreateHandler();
})
```

Comment: I'll check it out soon

Comment: This was the right answer for us

Answer (score 0):

It should work. The only thing I see obviously wrong is that you're passing just the test host address to `WithUrl`, whereas, it should be the full path to your hub, i.e. something like:

```
.WithUrl(new Uri(server.BaseAddress, Consts.TethysWebSocketPath))
```

Answer (score 0):

The [above answer by Brennan](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51716319) is great, if you want to use an access token you will need to add just one more line to that solution

```cs
string accessToken = // getting it from someplace.
builder.WithUrl(new Uri(server.BaseAddress, "ws"), o =>
{
    o.AccessTokenProvider = () => Task.FromResult<string?>(accessToken);
    o.HttpMessageHandlerFactory = _ => server.CreateHandler();
})
```